# Access token doesn't work after July 2013 breaking changes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

Application access token was working earlier but after the breaking changes, the application stopped working. The error I am getting is

```
(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint
```

I have used the code below for the access token

```cs
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new {
    client_id = XXXX,
    client_secret = XXXXX,
    grant_type = "client_credentials",
    scope = "publish_stream"
});
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe it will work for you.

Add FB APPid in info.plist

```
FacebookAppID --Your FB id
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
tried using FacebookAppId  but same error- 

dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = ApplicationId,
                        client_secret = ApplicationSecret,
                        grant_type = "client_credentials",
                        scope = "publish_stream",
                        FacebookAppID = "xxxxxxx"

                    });
```

Comment: this needs to be a comment on an answer, or edit to your original post - this is the section for answers to your question